# Not able to create indexed view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

consider this sql

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyView1] ([ID],[VisitDate],[StartDate] ,[EndDate],[MyCount])
WITH SCHEMABINDING  

AS
SELECT     id, VisitDate,dateadd(dd,-10,VisitDate),dateadd(dd,10,VisitDate),
count_BIG(*)as MyCount
FROM         dbo.Visits2
group by id,VisitDate
```

I am trying to create a clustered index on this view on id,VisitDate.I am getting the following error.

> Cannot create the clustered index 'IX_!!' on view 'CI_DB.dbo.MyView4'
>   because the select list of the view contains an expression on result of 
>   aggregate function or grouping column.
>   Consider removing expression on result of aggregate function or
>   grouping column from select list.

Comment: I wouldn't include the 2 calculated columns in the definition anyway even if you can find a way around the error. This is trivial to calculate at runtime and will just mean the view storage takes more pages.

Comment: @Martin. but i have an index on Visitdate and when i use this dateadd fn my index would be meaningless right ?i really want those to be precalculated and persisted.

Comment: The index wouldn't be used if you did `WHERE dateadd(dd,-10,VisitDate) = @startdate` but that is of course easy to re-arrange as `WHERE VisitDate = dateadd(dd,10,@startdate)`

Comment: @martin . i have something like this `VisitDate 
 BETWEEN dateadd(day,-10,Patients.VisitDate) AND dateadd(day,-1,Patients.VisitDate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the sql to

```
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyView2] ([ID],[VisitDate],[StartDate] ,[EndDate],[MyCount])
WITH SCHEMABINDING  

AS
SELECT     id, VisitDate,
dateadd(day,duration,VisitDate) startdate
,dateadd(day,duration,VisitDate) enddate,
count_BIG(*)as MyCount
FROM         dbo.Visits3
group by id,VisitDate,dateadd(day,duration,VisitDate),dateadd(day,duration,VisitDate)

GO
```

Seems like you cant specify a direct value like 10 inside the function and group by clause.Now it works!!

Answer (score 1):

[This is a known issue since 2006.](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/238685/valid-indexed-view-raises-error-8668)

If you have an aggregation in an indexed view, and both a field and an expression applied to the field are in the `GROUP BY` (which I'm assuming you just left out of  your sample code), the engine won't allow you to create it.

There are some workarounds but they aren't very straightforward.  Basically you need to fool the engine into thinking the fields are different.

Comment: i dont have anything else in my `Group By` Clause

Comment: u want me to add `dateadd(dd,-10,VisitDate),dateadd(dd,10,VisitDate)`in Group BY Clause?

Comment: @AshleyJohn yep, give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty clear error message, your view is not one that can be indexed. THere are many many conditions on what kinds of views can be indexed.